# How can I create a Get request in node.js to sum a request by a date (It could be month, day or year)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a route called '/test_cancellation', which is returning all the cancellations by account_mananger, fronter, closer, management_fee, cancellation date. I want to create a route that return the total of management_fee (sum) by year or month.

This is the route that I have right now:

[image]

And, this is the json that is returning:

[image]

I want to created a route that use the cancellation_date as parameter to return only the year with total of management_fee (Sum). Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is group the year, also add a sort to arrange by order:

```
CacellationKPI.aggregate([
    {
       $group: {
           _id: { $year: "$cancellation_date" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
       }
    }
    {
       $sort: {
          count: -1
       }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. But, there is a way to do sum management_fee and being shown by year, month or day. In the code above is counting all the cancellations by year (Which is awesome) by I want to sum management_fee by year